# Detecting Tab Key Press On Bluetooth Keyboard

Tags: ipad, cocoa-touch, uikit, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

If a bluetooth keyboard is connected to an iPad, I can pick up the **enter** key with:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
```

but what do I use if I need to detect the **tab** key as well?

FYI using your hardware keyboard in the ios simulator is essentially the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good luck; see the below post for a thorough dive into this question. :)

http://weaklyreferenced.wordpress.com/2012/11/13/responding-to-the-tab-and-shift-tab-keys-on-ios-5-ios-6-with-an-external-keyboard/

The short answer is that iOS (at least as of iOS 6) does not expose a similar method for the `tab` key, and you'll have to get creative in order to detect it.

Comment: Ooh, very good solution. I may not do it the exact way they have it, but it's probably what gets me to solving the issue at which point I'll come back and give you the points :)

Comment: i have tried that one, but i am not getting output. Can you send me demo app?